# How do you make a MovieClip inside a scrollPane move to a new location using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, scrollpane

I have an MC that is a list and it's inside a scrollPane. I want to make the list jump to a new location by clicking an object inside the MC.

I do not want the user to manually scroll the list. However, I'm not sure how to reference the MC in the scrollPane.

I'm lost on the coding, have some incredibly basic AS3 going on that doesn't work:

```
scrollPane.source = List1;
scrollPane.setSize(440, 610);
scrollPane.scrollDrag = true;
```

The list works in that I can manually scroll through it. So I tried this code to see if I coul move the MC inside the scrollPane up 300 pixels--it obviously didn't work:

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveList1);

function moveList1(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    
    scrollPane.source.List1.y = -300;
    
}
```

I'm assuming since the MC "List1" isn't actually on the stage is where I'm getting tripped up.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I asked a similar question a long time ago that I since forgot about.

The **solution** is:

```
"scrollPane instance name".verticalScrollPosition = "wherever you want the pane to scroll to".
```

*Example usage code:*

```
scrollPane.verticalScrollPosition = 100;
```